# DataTables: Header and body not aligned

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I have a select combobox to show/hide a div where there's a DataTable. The problem is that when the div is shown the DataTable header and body are not aligned. The DataTable get populated from database using php.

**UPDATE**

> If the div is not hidden when the page is loaded, the datatable loads
>   aligned. It gets misaligned when it is hidden and is show by using the
>   select combobox.

**Code:**

```
<table id="dtBasicExample" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-sm" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
  <thead>
   <tr>
    <th>Código<i class="fa fa-sort"></i></th>
    <th>Producto<i class="fa fa-sort"></i></th>
    <th>% Exo.<i class="fa fa-sort"></i></th>
  </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>

  </tbody>
  <tfoot>
  </tfoot>
</table> 


<script>

$(document).ready(function(){

   $($.fn.dataTable.tables(true)).DataTable()
      .columns.adjust();

  $.noConflict(true);
  //cambiar idioma de Tabla

    $('#dtBasicExample').DataTable({
            "scrollX": true,
            "order": [[1, "asc"]],
            "language":{
                "lengthMenu": "Mostrar _MENU_ registros por pagina",
                "info": "Mostrando pagina _PAGE_ de _PAGES_",
                "infoEmpty": "No hay registros disponibles",
                "infoFiltered": "(filtrada de _MAX_ registros)",
                "loadingRecords": "Cargando...",
                "processing":     "Procesando...",
                "search": "Buscar:",
                "zeroRecords":    "No se encontraron registros coincidentes",
                "paginate": {
                    "next":       "Siguiente",
                    "previous":   "Anterior"
                },                  
            }
        });

    $('.dataTables_length').addClass('bs-select');

});

</script>
```

**Output**

[image: Output]

Comment: Do you want the header and body to be 'physically joined' or are you just wanting visual alignment. The latter would be a purely CSS issue, but I note that you haven't used that flag.  An example of your current output would be good.

Comment: I added the output image. I just want both to be aling no matter how

Comment: When you said 'not aligned', I thought you meant slightly squint, but that is quite extreme. Can you show us the source - as rendered? Do both tables end up with the same CSS classes? Basic problem appears to be that the header is left-aligned, but the 'body' is centred - can't tell why without looking a bit deeper at the CSS in use.

Comment: Can you try this  chained last table with adjust().draw() like this: $('#dtBasicExample').DataTable({options}).columns.adjust().draw();

Comment: @MikeBrockington Is only 1 table and I am not using CSS just the code you see in my post

Comment: @MikeBrockington check out the update I wrote in my post